# Lyapunov stability and Lasalle's Theorem

Tags: nonlinear-system, lyapunov-functions

If a given function V is radially unbounded, does it also imply that it is positive definite? I am trying to solve a stability problem (prove GAS) with and without Lasalle's theorem. It is easy enough to solve using Lasalle's theorem as I can prove the function is radially unbounded but do not know how to see if V (Lyapunov function) is positive definite.

Comment: Of course not, why would it need to be?

Comment: For example $-x^2$ is radially unbound but not positive definite.